# How to return the indexes that tell the position of largest to smallest integers of an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Suppose I have an array of unique integers that contains 9 elements.

```
array = [3,5,7,9,2,4,8,1,6]
```

How do I return an array of indexs that tell me the position of the original array of integers from largest to smallest?

```
index_of_largest_to_smallest = [3,6,2,8,1,5,0,4,7]
```

So this would tell me the largest number is at position 3, and the second largest is at position 6 etc.

I tried `array.sort`, but that sorts the array from largest to smallest.
I also tried `array.each_with_index` but couldn't get it to return another array.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)". We need to see evidence of your effort to solve this. Did you research the problem? Why didn't that help? If it did, did you write code? If not, why? If you did, what is the smallest version of the code that demonstrates the problem you had? As is, it doesn't look like you did those things and want us to write the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Via [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort), [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map), [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-last) and [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse):

```
[3,5,7,9,2,4,8,1,6].each_with_index   #=> [[3, 0], [5, 1], [7, 2], [9, 3], [2, 4], [4, 5], [8, 6], [1, 7], [6, 8]]
                   .sort              #=> [[1, 7], [2, 4], [3, 0], [4, 5], [5, 1], [6, 8], [7, 2], [8, 6], [9, 3]]
                   .map(&:last)       #=> [7, 4, 0, 5, 1, 8, 2, 6, 3]
                   .reverse           #=> [3, 6, 2, 8, 1, 5, 0, 4, 7]
```

Comment: +1, Clean, clear, concise. P.S.: One can also pass a block to sort the array `.sort{|a, b| b[0] <=> a[0] }` in reverse order, which means: `arr.each_with_index.sort{|a, b| b[0] <=> a[0] }.map(&:last)` will also work just the same.

Comment: after seeing this, I can't believe how easy it is. Thanks for the comments, it helped me understand that I can break problems down into small steps and keep transforming the array until I get the desired result.

Comment: David, [Enumerable#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) compares pairs of elements `a` and `b` of the object being sorted with the *spaceship* operator, `<=>`. Here `a` and `b` are arrays, so it uses [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). Read that doc, especially the third paragraph, so see how it works here.

Answer (score 5):

```
array.each_index.sort_by { |i| -array[i] }
  #=> [3, 6, 2, 8, 1, 5, 0, 4, 7]
```

See the form of [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) and [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). Note that `Array#each_index` returns an enumerator when, as here, no block is given.

Comment: This type of wizardry is something I can only dream of aspiring to. I will end up using this solution because it is super concise. Thank you!

Comment: It won't be long before you yawn when reading code that now seems like wizardry. Note that @Stefan's solution, though using more methods, is the standard way of solving your problem, and may well be faster than mine.